# Tip is behind but pull changes has not effect

Tags: git

I had made some changes to a branch named `sandbox` and I committed the changes and then attempted to push them to the github version of sandbox. I received this message

```
To git@github.com:obromios/golf_mentor.git
 ! [rejected]        sandbox -> sandbox (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:obromios/golf_mentor.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

I could not recall doing anything that would have got the two out of sync, like pushing from another machine. Anyway, I duly did `git pull origin sandbox` and a merge was successfully done.  But when I did a `git diff` between the newly merged commit and the previous commit that was rejected, I could see no difference.  However, I could now push the merged commit to github.  I have seen this behaviour a few times before, any ideas what is causing it, and how to fix it without doing pull?

Comment: `git log --decorate --graph` will show you the true history of the repository and what diverged.

Comment: And if it tells you to pull, _first_ do `git fetch` and then look at the decorated log (add `--all` to see all refs, including remote branches and `FETCH_HEAD`). You can still run `pull` as normal once you've figured out what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible this is caused by merge commits that have been done on the github website.

If you do a merge on github you will always get a merge commit. For example, perhaps you did a merge from master to sandbox, and perhaps there were no changes (but the empty merge commit still got created).

Having an extra commit upstream will prevent you from pushing until you pull it, even if the merge commit doesn't bring any new changes when you pull it (which seems to be the case here).

I would suggest keeping a close eye on any merges / pull requests to minimise this happening.